# revealjs_presentation in R: code and out put

Tags: css, r, rstudio, markdown, reveal.js

I have a problem in my revealjs_presentation. I need to show my code and output. Therefore in need a long slide, but I have this:

[image]

My code:

```
output:
revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
css: slides.css
theme: night
self_contained: false
incremental: true
transition: none
```

---

Is the problem with my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add another slide with "slide" effect. It is not exactly what you ask but i think is the only way:

````
## Slide 1
```{r, eval=F}
    # (Your plot code)
    # Will show your code whithout evaluation (not dislaying plot)
```

## Slide 2 {data-background-transition="zoom" data-transition="zoom"}

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.height=6, fig.width=10, fig.align="center"}

    # (Your plot code)
    # Only your plot will be displayed.
```
````